# How to exclude routes from Angular routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, routes

Consider an application using angular.js routing. Assume one wants to delegate routes `/this` and `/that` to angular, and that these are coded in the app similarly to:

```
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/this', { //..})
      .when('/that', { //::})
      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/this'
      });
```

If HTML5 mode is used, serverside routes must be configured in order to delegate to angular. What I have now is:

```
app.get('/*', function(req,res){
    res.render('home.ejs');
    });
```

Now, I would like to have some routes, e.g., `/those`, handled directly by the server. In the current configuration `/those` is intercepted by `/*`. I know that a possible solution would be to enumerate all angular routes also in the server, namely:

```
app.get('/this', function(req,res){
        res.render('home.ejs');
        });
app.get('/that', function(req,res){
        res.render('home.ejs');
        });
```

This works, but is ugly and slippery as it is easy to forget something and generate bugs.

**Question:**
I was wondering if there is a way to leave `/*` in the serverside router, and specify that this should not include `/those`, for which a specific `app.get('/those',..)` is to be implemented.

Comment: The answer linked in my last comment will probably cure what ails ya.

Comment: I have read that post, and I am not sure it contains the answer to this question. The point here is that even if have a `<a target=_self >` tag which jumps angular, `/those` will be intercepted by `/*` and return home rather than the appropriate content for `/those`.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Flag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to configure the express server routes similarly to:

```
app.get('/those',..);
...
app.get('*', function(req,res){
    res.render('home.ejs');
    });
```

where the route `'*'` is at the very end of the routes file. This way `'*'` intercepts only the routes which are not explicitly specified earlier in the file.